# How to set max_filesize for clamav in docker-compose.yml

Tags: docker, docker-compose, environment-variables, clamav

I'm trying to setup a docker container with clamav and am struggling to allow for larger files to be scanned. I've set up my docker-compose.yml like this:

```
version: "3.3"
services:
  clamav:
    image: clamav/clamav:latest
    environment:
      CLAMD_CONF_MaxFileSize: 250M
      CLAMD_CONF_MaxScanSize: 250M
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "3310:3310"
```

but that doesn't seem to do it (I keep getting a Broken Pipe Error). I presume I'm just using the wrong variables, but I can't seem to find the right ones.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to scan relatively larger files, setting up the `docker-compose.yaml` as follows:

```
version: "3"
services:
  clamav:
    image: mkodockx/docker-clamav:alpine
    environment:
      CLAMD_CONF_MaxFileSize: 250M
      CLAMD_CONF_MaxScanSize: 250M
      CLAMD_CONF_StreamMaxLength: 250M
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "3310:3310"
```

I'm using a different image `mkodockx/docker-clamav:alpine` though.

Answer (score 0):

According to my information this is not possible in the official image of `clamav/clamav:stable` but it would be a great improvement of the image.
We also wanted to use the official image. So our solution has been to mount the `/var/lib/clamav` directory and the `/etc/clamav` directories to a persistent volume. Then we change the `/etc/clamav/clamd.conf` after running the container and restart it after the configuration.